# Packaging Readme and License files

Tags: java, ant

I have an ANT build script that automatically creates a jar from my code, then zips that plus java docs, source files, external library dependencies, a LICENSE and README files, then pushes the created zip to a website directory for users to download.

Right now, my license file is literally `LICENSE` and readme is `README`, both without file extensions.

Windows machine's seem to freak out when a file has no extension and doesn't know how to handle it. Worse, I've noticed the built-in program notepad on windows does not respect my files's line ending characters, so it all gets jumbled into a single line. Notepad++ and others have no problem, and on linux and mac the issue is non-existent really.

Bringing us to the question. For legal and/or usability reasons, what is recommended for these file names - extensions (such as .txt or .md or .rtf) or no extensions. I'm unsure the legalities of a "regular joe" user not being able to easily open the license, and therefore may claim it was not reasonably displayed or made available (and therefore violations of the license may happen). However, I find it frustrating to have to change my regular project structure (and how i've become accustomed to things) simply to make windows behave like it should.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to add an extension to your license and readme files, I would suggest `txt`, as they are text only file (I suppose).

Take a look a [Windows vx. Unix file endings](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html). Some editors are clever enough to detect it. Notepad isn't.

**UPDATE**

For information on how to add license to your software, get some hints at [How to use GNU licenses for your own software](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html).

Comment: I was preferring to not add an extension... for deployment to *nix only environments, this would be no problem. But for a windows deployment, the user now has to be assumed capable of opening this file (by right clicking --> open with --> notepad). Is this "safe" for a license or should I just rename them to *.txt ?

Comment: You can show the license in your installer/the first time the application is run and aks the user to agree. Or you can add in your application `help` a dialog that show the license file. In both cases you will not need the extension, because there are other means to "open" the file.

Comment: thanks for your help so far! This is specifically for a library intended for other developers to use. So there is no way to have a EULA dialog or what-have-you. I realize developers should be smart enough to open the file, but I wanted to get thoughts and opinions on if someone could use the lack of extension (difficulty to open file with normal OS operation, ie. double-click) as a means to circumvent the license?

Comment: Read the update: you can add an disclaimer text on top of your interfaces saying "(c) SnakeDoc. This software is distributed under the terms of My License. You should have received a copy of the license with this software (located on {where}) or you can get a copy on `http://mywebsite.com/mylicense`)"